# Powerapps Gallery cannot show newly added files on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I created one gallery to display the files in sharepoint folder.
It worked one week before but today when I check it, I found that it failed to show the files I added today, only shows the files I added before...
Does anyone know what happend?..
Here is my code: SortByColumns(Filter(Documents_1,'Folder path'="Shared Documents/folder1/folder2"&file_Gallery_2.Selected.Name&"/"),"Created",Descending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default powerapps retrieves only the first 500 items from sharepoint lists or libraries, it can be change in app settings and get the first 2000 items.
[image: Powerapps settings].

If you have a list with more than 500 items the best way is using a filter by search input text.

Comment: Hi Pedro, I found this online and it works for me: If(
  Connection.Connected,
  ClearCollect(localData, 'YourDataSource'),
  SaveData(localData, "saveLocalData");
  LoadData(localData, "saveLocalData", true)
)

Comment: Wonderfull, I'm reading powerapps documentation now, SaveData and LoadData is the new for us, powerapps developers. Woow this is really insteristing I have some applications in production that need this. Thanks @Momoe.

if you want read the topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-savedata-loaddata